# VBA Convert Cell Values to Text in all Worksheets in Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting the below code to work. I am trying to convert cells in all excel worksheets populated in a folder using general function Range. Value = Range . Text. The formula works if I input just (Code 1) in one excel file. However, if I incorporate this code into the VBA code (2), to perform the routine for all excel files in a folder I am getting an error.

CODE 1)

```
    Sub Test23()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("B11:G200")
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
    With cel
        cel.Value = cel.Text
    End With
    Next cel

   End Sub
```

CODE 2)

```
        Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
      

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("B11:G200")
For Each cel In rng.Cells
     With cel
        cel.Value = cel.Text
    End With
Next cel

    
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: " I am getting an error." is not a very useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code.

Comment: You define `wb` but use it. `Set rng = wb.worksheets(1).Range("B11:G200")` (might be the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is an easy fix. If this works for you, you can click on the check mark next to this answer to accept it as an answer.

Your code will work well if you make a few minor tweaks:

First, in CODE 2), you forgot to add the else statement to your If. This meant that your code never actually did anything with the myPath variable, even if the user chose a folder. Because myPath was always empty, your code did exactly what you wanted it to do: GoTo ResetSettings. I added an ElseIf condition for you with a comment to explain it.

Second, if you ever change a UI setting via VBA, make sure you error trap to reset those settings in case something goes wrong. I added an On Error statement at the top of your code to make sure you never leave your users stranded -- even if you're the user!

Good luck, and don't forget to accept this as an answer if it works for you!

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandler 'added this so that if something breaks, you remember to reset the screenupdating
'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            GoTo NextCode 'if other than -1, user hit cancel so go to NextCode to kick off the resetsettings (this seems redundant, why not go directly to ResetSettings?)
        ElseIf .Show = -1 Then 'this could also be a simple Else with no condition attached; I tend to use ElseIf with a specific condition to make sure I get exactly what I want
                myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"  'if user hit the action button, add it to myPath -- your earlier code skipped this part because there was no else statement
        End If
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings 'before the change I made above, you would always jump right to ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
      

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("B11:G200")
For Each cel In rng.Cells
     With cel
        cel.Value = cel.Text
    End With
Next cel

    
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub 'exit the sub if we got this far without an error so that we don't run the error handler unless there is an error
    
ErrHandler:
MsgBox ("Sorry, something went wrong. The error code was " & Err.Number & " on line: " & Erl) 'tell the user what went wrong
GoTo ResetSettings 'cleanup

End Sub
```